# What is the PowerShell object name for a string?

Tags: string, powershell

I have a simple REGEX method to obtain the last alphabetic characters of a string by removing letters and numbers which precede it:

`"TEST02TEST" | %{($_ -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1')}`

the output for this is obviously TEST

What if I want to select it at the end of a pipeline? What do I call it, what is it's object name?

Basically I am trying to use add-member get both the refined string and the original string like this:

```
"TEST02TEST" | %{($_ -Replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1') | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OriginalString -Value $_ -PassThru} | select OriginalString, (something here)
```

What is the "something here"?

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have a series of strings you need to tackle, like:

```
$strings = "TEST02TEST", "Blah123Something", "xyz0897654ABC"
```

you could do this:

```
foreach ($str in $strings) {
    $str | Select-Object @{Name = 'OriginalString'; Expression = {$_}},
                         @{Name = 'LastWordChars';  Expression = {$_ -replace '\D*\d*(\w+)', '$1'}}
}
```

Output:

```
OriginalString   LastWordChars
--------------   -------------
TEST02TEST       TEST
Blah123Something Something
xyz0897654ABC    ABC
```

Instead of `@{Name = 'LastWordChars';  Expression = {$_ -replace '\D*\d*(\w+)', '$1'}}` you could also use the regex `-split` operator:

```
@{Name = 'LastWordChars';  Expression = {($_ -split '\d+')[-1]}}
```

<sup>Of course, the property name 'LastWordChars' is totally up to you.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Theo - this is how that refactors: "TEST02TEST" | % {$_ | Select-Object @{Name = 'OriginalString'; Expression = {$_}}, @{Name = 'LastWordChars';  Expression = {$_ -replace '\D*\d*(\w+)', '$1'}}}

Comment: @IanB Yes, but on a single string `"TEST02TEST"` there is no need to do a `ForEach-Object` (aka `%`). This is the case when you are parsing an array of strings.